# Bicep: How to concat tags

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I am using a Bicep script to create resources in Mcirosoft Azure.

I have defined a variable with the common tags that are the same for all resources.But now, when assigning this variable to a resource, I want to add more tags that are only for this resource.

However, I have not yet found a way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-array#union) function to merge object.

In this sample, I've defined a parameter with the common tags and merge the object with resource specific tags:

```bicep
param commonTags object = {
  commonTag1: 'commonTag1'
  commonTag2: 'commonTag2'
}

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2019-06-01' = {
  name: 'my storage account name'
  ...
  tags: union(commonTags, {
    storageTag1: 'storageTag1'
    storageTag2: 'storageTag2'
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for...

Comment: Thank you, that's not exactly what I was looking for, but did need to override a node label from standard set of resource labels, for a specific AKS node pool, in Bicep:
`nodeLabels: union(requiredTags, {
    application: '${application}-infra'})`